# the kernel trick and linear regression

Tags: regression, linear-model, nonlinear-regression, kernel-trick

This question is inspired by [this](https://www.researchgate.net/post/if_there_is_no_correlation_is_there_a_need_to_run_linear_regression) and the answer by Hamed.

Let us say the underlying data generation process is:

```
 y = 3x + sin(x)
```

So pretty non linear. I understand that the linear regression only has to be linear in parameters. So by transforming the original IV x into 2 new IVs x1 and x2:

```
x1=x and x2=sin(x)
```

one can estimate the parameters using this linear regression formula:

```
y = alpha * x1 + beta * x2
```

or in R speak:

```
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 - 1)
```

is this correct and is this the kernel trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this correct? Yes, except that it's not the kernel trick. There are two equivalent approaches to a regression problem. One is to write the response variable $y$ as a linear combination of basis functions $\phi(x)$ as $y(x) = \sum_i \omega_i \phi_i(x)$, $i=1,2$ (2 in this case, you could have infinite). This is what you are doing, and what you are calling new input variables are the basis functions evaluated at the old variables, $\phi_1(x) = x$ and $\phi_2(x) = \sin(x)$. The weights in that linear combination are what you look for.

The kernel trick is to write the regression problem as $y(x) = \sum_n y_n K(x,x_n)$, $n=1,2,...,N$, where  $N$ is the number of data points and where the kernel function $K$ can be written in terms of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$. An alternative is to directly propose a kernel with suitable properties and forget about basis functions $\phi$. One must take into account that training a model based on the kernel approach involves estimating $N$ parameters, probably much more than the 2 you have in the basis function approach (what's the benefit then? is that you don't need to assume any functional form such as $x$ and $\sin(x)$, so the approach is more flexible. Also, while slow for training, is fast for predicting sot that's no problem.)

This (free) book https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf talks about this in great detail (but is not very straightforward to dive in).

Comment: Thanks. From a classification point of view, I always thought the kernel trick is to transform the data into a high dimensional space to make them linear separable (see radial basis function networks). I thought I do something similar here as I transform x -> x1, x2

Comment: "From a classification point of view, I always thought the kernel trick is to transform the data into a high dimensional space to make them linear separable (see radial basis function networks)", that's what is known kernel trick in that context, I agree

Comment: My point was that a kernel approach is something more general, and is at the core of any linear regression problem. When you assume a kernel you are implicitly assuming a set of basis functions (maybe an infinite number of them). When you assume basis functions, you are implicitly defining a kernel form (an this form can be easily obtained with simple matrix operations)

Comment: Thanks. I have Bishop's book as hardcopy. Need to read that part again (-:

Comment: You are welcome. It's a nice book but I find that it's not so easy to just read a single page on it, normally you need a lot of contexts to understand it. I recommend sections 6.1 and 3.3.3. If you found my answer useful, you can mark it with the check mark on the left :)

Comment: I will accept don't worry.

Comment: I think the coefficient for the kernel trick equation should be $a_n$ instead of $x_n$ (which is the training point). One thing about kernel trick is that you have to embed the training points into the model, whilst a simple linear regression model can independent.

Comment: @syockit, indeed there's an error, thank you for pointing that out. Instead of $x_n$ it should be the values $y_n$ (see e.g., equation 3.61 of the book I talked about in the answer).